# Is there a particular reason the less than operator is used as default comparison for max pq?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

Why couldn't the greater operator be used as the comparison? Is there a particular advantage in using less than?

Comment: All the other STL facilities use less-than. Consequently, a lot of classes are written that implement `operator<` but not necessarily `operator>`. If `priority_queue` weren't consistent, it won't be usable with such classes without extra work. So basically, it's to minimize the size of the interface that the user needs to provide in order to use the library.

Comment: There is no advantage, technically. It's just for consistency. Besides, the minimum requirement for sorting is defined with by some ordering relationship, and the STL chose some 'form of` operator <`

Comment: If you want to be equal opportunity for all operators, check out the boost class template <typename T> boost::less_than_comparable<T> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589353/what-is-the-minimum-set-of-operators-i-need-to-overload/4589464?s=2|37.0776#4589464

Comment: As long as the operators implement/impose a strict weak ordering, `std::less` and `std::greater` could each be the default. But, you have to pick one, and less seems more natural most of the time, so it's a sane default. You can always override it if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

There are two aspects to your question:

- Firstly, that's technically not correct: Most algorithms (not sure which one exactly you mean) use `std::less` as a default. However, that default can be overridden. The important point is the behaviour of the comparison, i.e. that it imposes a "strict-weak ordering", a term you will find mentioned in many texts on the topic and (I believe) even the standard itself.
- Secondly, doing things in ascending order is often "natural" and it is the default throughout the C++ standard library.